# Filter a Dictionary by value where value is a list of string using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following structure:
`Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

For example, I wanted to retrieve all the entry that have as a value a string longer than 3 character, this is what I've tried:

```
mydictionary.Where(s => s.Value.Where(word => word.Length == 3).ToList().Count > 0) as Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

But what I get is a null value, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "I wanted to retrieve all the entry that have as a value a string longer than 3 character" - your condition is wrong, you are looking for words that are "exactly" 3 characters, not words that are 4 characters or greater. `Where(word => word.Length > 3)`. Voted to close as typo or unreproducible.

Comment: `var = mydictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value.Any(item => item.Length > 3)).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit `Any` method instead of `Where` and `Count`:

```
var result = mydictionary
  .Where(pair => pair.Value.Any(word => word.Length > 3)) // longer than 3 chars
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Note, that you should *materialize* with a help of `ToDictionary` instead of *cast* `as Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: This worked, thanks. Can you please explain why I needed to materialize with a help of ToDictionary instead of cast because it’s not clear to me. Thanks again

Comment: @Max_Power89: `mydictionary.Where(...)` returns `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>`, just a *enumeration* **not** a *collection* `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, that's why when you try to cast it you get `null` as the result. To create a dictionary (or collections like array, list, hashset) from `IEnumerable<T>` we should *materialize* the enumeration with a help of `To.Dictionary()` (`ToArray()`, `ToList()` ...)
`